# Como desativar o fechamento do modal através da tecla ESC no modal do UI-Bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

No `ui-bootstrap`, eu consigo desabilitar o fechamento do modal ao clicar no fundo preto através da opção `{backdrop: 'static'}`.

Porém agora preciso também de desativar a tecla <kbd>ESC</kbd>, pois quando aperta essa tecla, o modal é fechado.

Como fazer isso?

O modal que tenho atualmente está assim:

```
$uibModal.open({

    templateUrl: '/ng-views/os/form.html',

    backdrop: 'static',

    controller: 'OSFormController'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve configurar a opção `keyboard` para `false`

```
$uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: '/ng-views/temp/os/form.html',
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard : false,
    controller: 'OSFormController'
});
```

Comment: É isso mesmo. Funcionou. Valeu :D